# adding and removing studs to stairs for support

Tags: stairs, load-bearing, support

I would like to remove the purple section so I may walk under the stairs. Behind that purple section has open space that I have to crawl under to get too. The red markings is the stairs behind the studs. Should I add 4x4 studs where the blue markings are?[image]

Comment: That's a gluelam beam you want to chop into. It was designed by a structural engineer and custom built for your house for the exact loads that it's designed to support. If you really want to remove part of it, you should really contact a local structural engineer to determine what kind of support you'll need to replace that missing section with. Your plan could leave you with something as minor as a little sag in the stairs, or as major as a collapse of that garage wall. I wouldn't trust this to some internet strangers, no matter how well intentioned they may be

Comment: I will definitely let them handle it. Thanks

Comment: What @freeman said -- you *need* a local structural engineer.

Comment: I see you have the circular saw and sawzall in place and ready to go...